# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml:

Tags: javascript, html, svg

When I have an SVG picture with JavaScript chrome says 'Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml'.
I can include it with iframe or embed TAG same result.
But when I change the mime type to something different the browser cannot render it.
So i guess "image/svg+xml" is correct?

SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" id="draw" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 480 480"> 
<defs>
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
]]>
</style>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="480" height="480" rx="0" ry="0" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />

</g>
<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
(function () { 

//Some code here

}());
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: How do you "change the mime type"?

Comment: The server responds for SVGz with: Content-Type: image / svg + xml
Content-Encoding: gzip

Comment: I was using embed tag previously (now iframe) then I tried it also with type="image/svg+xml" for the embed tag

Comment: Excuse me again, but is the SVG is displayed anyway what *is* the problem?

Comment: The console message in chrome. It is not a real problem. But other developers inspecting your code will always be curious if there could be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `image/svg+xml` is the correct internet media type for SVG content, see [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image).

Comment: Then why chrome is still complaining about it and what can we do about it (if we can do something ...)

Comment: What version of chrome? Seems like it has been fixed for a while: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128988

Comment: Sorry actually it's a QTwebkit engine, I havent noticed that chrome moved away from webkit to blink a while ago... I guess there is nothing to do about it unless update the QTwebkit engine :(

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem for a long time but it appears application/svg-xml is the correct mime.

Refer to this https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/266 for more details. The mime/svg-xml may be vulnerable too.